# check another script's output from within the script

Tags: linux, bash

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

path=$1

if [[ ./first.sh "$path" == "0" ]]
     echo "0"
fi
```

The script "first.sh" prints a number using echo. Now in the second script i wanna check if the output of the first script was "0" and if so, print "0"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the output of a command/script run in shell, wrap it in `$()`. For example `variable=$(ls "$path")` reads the output of `ls` for the given path into `variable`.

Applying this to your problem

```
#!/bin/bash

path=$1
output=$(./first.sh "$path")
if [[ "$output" == "0" ]]; then
     echo "0"
fi
```

Please note that i also removed some errors (use `; then` after the if statement).

Comment: thanks! is it possible to do something like this: `if [[ $(ls -d */ "$path") = ""]]; then` ? i wanna check if the path has no subdirectories

Comment: If you want to see if there is subdirectories, you can use find. Its a very usefull utility (check http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html). `find "$path" -maxdepth 0 -type d | wc -l` will give you the number of subdirectories. This should be 1 in case its empty, because only `.` will be returned for empty dirs.